# How to save Image(imported from gallery of phone to android app) and save into android app local directory?

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard

I have searched all questions related to this but i did not get solution. My requirement is From my Android app, user can choose image from gallery of phone and set this as his favorite. My question is photo taken from gallery need to be saved to app local directory(This directory is not visible to user because it will store in app).If user remove the image from phone gallery then also app should show his favorite image. So i need to save local directory.Please help me on this. Thanks in Advance. I know following code is used to store to sdcard but i need to save image from sdcard to local folder of app.

```
  BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        Bitmap bm = LoadImage(imagePath, bmOptions);
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/MyFolder");    
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
               bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
               out.flush();
               out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for example:

```
 File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
       File image = new File(path,imageFileName );
```

Your image will be save in your app directory.